# Distinguishing programmatic Bing AJAX Map navigation from user pan/zoom and window resizes

Tags: javascript, bing-maps

I have a scenario where I need to continually keep a particular `LocationRect` best-fit (i.e. result of `map.setView({ bounds: myLocationRect })`) visible in the map across window resizes or tablet orientation changes until the user interacts with the map to change the current view.

I need some guidance here as to how to do that.  Considering how many different mouse and keyboard interactions can change the view, I don't want to filter all of those interactions; it seems more appropriate to filter out the scenarios where the map's containing HTML element changes size.

I've already attempted to do this via tracking the previous width/height of the map element and listening to the `targetviewchanged` event; however, that has not worked reliably for me.  The reason being, if I reset the view, I cannot reliably suspend listening to `targetviewchanged`.  For instance:

```
function resetView() {
    if(!_keepAoiInView) return; // unhook setInterval as well; omitted for brevity

    _suspend = true;
    _map.setView({ bounds: theBoundsIWant });
    _suspend = false;
}

function ontargetviewchanged() {
    // This suspend check doesn't work - 
    //  resetView() isn't always lower in the call stack;
    //  therefore, _suspend is set back to false before the
    //  targetviewchanged event fires.
    if(_suspend) return;

    _keepAoiInView = false;  // unhook setInterval as well; omitted for brevity
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't the only mouse event actually be `onmouseup` and `ontouchend` on the map element since any user interaction would involve a click/tap, or drag of some form?

Comment: @TorstenWalter, also the scroll wheel.

Comment: And a handful of keyboard events (arrow keys, plus, minus), and... (?)

Comment: And let's not forget the pinch gesture, too...  This is why filtering each event separately seems to be the wrong approach.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't seem to get `targetviewchanged` to work, perhaps it's worth reconsidering tracking other events.

You might be able to track all the different possible interactions more easily using [pointer.js](https://github.com/borismus/pointer.js). This way, you only need to capture a few types of events that, under the hood, represent many types of events. If it plays nicely with Bing Maps, that might solve the problem of mouse, touch, and possibly gesture events.

That probably won't solve the problem for keyboard events, I suspect, but perhaps monitoring those as well is manageable.